# How to position-absolute a div only vertically?

Tags: html, css

I have a flex-row of elements (e.g. two lines with flex-wrapped). When I click one of those elements a popup (green box) should be opened directly under this element (that's why I need an absolute positioning) and those popups should all have the same width (independent of which element is clicked).

The problem is since this absolute positioned div starts just under the clicked element, the starting point of this popup also varies on the x-axis. But I want all the popups start at the same point horizontally.

https://jsfiddle.net/h8f73Lpm/24/

This is what I currently have:
[image]

This is what I want to achieve, when I click on an element in the first row:
[image]

.. and when i click on an element on the second row:
[image]

This is a simplified version of my situation. Since we also have to consider the responsiveness the actual number of rows and elements vary. I would prefer a css-only solution.

```css
.flexlist {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.entry {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 96px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 1px;
}

.selected {
  background: red;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  background: green;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexlist">
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry selected">
    <div class="absolute"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you consider a JS-based solution? I don't think it's possible using CSS only.

Comment: @Terry he is a colleague of mine that's why i can also answer your question..  JS would be our latest chance, and we know can handle it with JS. We just wanted to ask the question if there is any possibility to achieve this with only CSS..

Comment: @akcasoy are you allowed to change the HTML ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes, as long as we do not have to change some other places in the structure.. hard to describe here. BTW, as an extension i can say, the X starting points of the popups, must not be defined at all, as long as they all have the same starting X point. For example, when we can show the popups centered relative to viewport (if this somehow can make the problem easier to handle..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> should be opened directly under this element (that's why I need an absolute positioning)

Can be achieve without `position:absolute`

Here is an idea using CSS grid where you add the pop-up element after the selected one not inside it:

```css
.flexlist {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit,minmax(96px,1fr));
  grid-auto-flow:dense; /* this is important for the trick and will give the correct placement */
  max-width: 700px;
  margin:20px;
}

.entry {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 1px;
}

.selected {
  background: red;
}

.pop-up {
  z-index:2;
  grid-column:1/-1; /* full width */
  height: 0; /* take 0 height similar to position:absolute */
}
.pop-up > div {
  background: rgba(0,128,0,0.8);
  height:80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexlist">
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry selected"></div>
    <div class="pop-up">
      <div></div>
    </div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
</div>

<div class="flexlist">
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry "></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry selected"></div>
    <div class="pop-up">
      <div></div>
    </div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
</div>

<div class="flexlist">
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry "></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry selected"></div>
    <div class="pop-up">
      <div></div>
    </div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
  <div class="entry"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much! just one thing: by adding this "pseudo grid element" the grid-gap gets doubled. any idea how to prevent that? see: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gso3bmpc/3/)

Comment: i got it to work by only setting the column-gap and replacing the row gap by a margin-bottom for the .entry-elements: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9zt2mhxL/1/)